# Mysql - Remove string pattern from string

Tags: mysql

I have some string values inside my Mysql database table. They are in this format:

```
title1|url1
# or
title1|url1\ntitle2|url2\ntitle3|url3
```

I want to remove all `url`s and pipe characters (`|`) from these values so they should be in this format after the operation:

```
title1
# or
title1\ntitle2\ntitle3
```

I tried this query so far (say my table is `table1` and the field is `values`):

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `values` = SUBSTRING_INDEX(`values`, '|', 1);
```

For values like `title1|url1` it works but for values like `title1|url1\ntitle2|url2` it returns `title1`.

How should I do that?

[UPDATE]
`url` is any url-like string, such as `http://www.example.com/` or `www.example.org` or `http://example.com` or anything else.

Comment: are they all either 1 title or 3 titles? could there be other number of titles?

Comment: Yes, there might be any number of title|url pairs.

Comment: I'm afraid there's no easy way to do this unless you install the regex_replace udf

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE `table1` SET `values` = REPLACE (`values`, '|url', '');
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer a bit?

Comment: I'm replacing all instances of `url|` with a blank string, using MySQL's `REPLACE` function. This answer was written before it was clarified that the field did not actually contain the text `url|`. In response to the updated question, I would say it's not possible without some sort of looping procedure.

Comment: If there's a lookup table containing all possible `title`s, it might be possible without a procedure.